# Function without parameters

Tags: vba, function

I have this function that counts a range of cells by a colored text. The original function uses two inputs (range and text color) as parameters. As I´m using it at different rows, I want that calculate the dynamic cells range automatically, but I don't know how to manage that parameters inside a vba function. This is my code. Hope someone can give me a hand... regards, M.

```
Function CountByColor()
'Function CountByColor(rng, cell)
Application.Volatile

Set MyCell = ActiveCell.Address

ActiveCell.Offset(-1, -2).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

'Set zRange = rng

Set zRange = MyRange
Set zCell = MyCell.Offset(0, -1)

zValue = cell.Value
zFontColor = zCell.font.color
zCellColor = zCell.Interior.color

CountByColor = 0

On Error Resume Next
For Each cell In zRange
    If cell.Value = zValue Then
        If cell.font.color = zFontColor Then
            If cell.Interior.color = zCellColor Then
            CountByColor = CountByColor + 1
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next
On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

The range parameter is created by "activecell.offset(-1, -2).select", and the text colored reference cell by "mycell.offset(0, -1)...

[This is my worksheet...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtg5X.jpg)

Comment: It's not clear what the function means to do. Is it invoked from a worksheet cell? If so you'll want to take a `ByVal Target As Range` parameter, and work off that instead of `ActiveCell`. Function should have a declared return type (`As Long`?)

Comment: Are your variables declared outside of the function -- or not declared at all? You might be able to replace the `on error resume next` with `if zrange is nothing then exit function`

Comment: Thanks Mathieu and Chillin for your help! The worksheet is a workgroup planner, plus a gantt diagram. The porpose of this vba function is to count how many blue cells you have inside a range of rows (blue cells means that a guy is on duty...). Yes, it's invoked from a worksheet cell (that one with "#¿NOMBRE?" on it, and it's also copied to the cells on the right). To be honest, I have no idea how to use ByVal Target as Range, but I'll check my vba books...
The function have no parameters at all.

Comment: I would like to calculate the parameters in a sort of automatic way, as the range of rows are the cells two columns to the left (Offset(-1, -2)), and the text color cell is the one at the left of the function cell (Offset(0, -1)).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach (a little simplified from your code...)

```
Function countcolor()
    Dim clr As Long, rng As Range, c As Range, rv As Long

    With Application.ThisCell '<< ThisCell is the cell calling the function
        clr = .Offset(0, -1).Interior.Color '<< color to look for...
        Set rng = .Parent.Range(.Offset(-1, -2), .Offset(-1, -2).End(xlUp))
    End With

    For Each c In rng.Resize(, 100).Cells '<< adjust resizing to suit...
        If c.Interior.Color = clr Then rv = rv + 1
    Next c

    countcolor = rv

End Function
```

[image]